# Java Swing form and cannot type text in newly added jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield

I was asked to change a previously made java swing form to add a `JTextField` which would respond to keystrokes. I added the text field to the form, tried to force focus on it with no success and even if I click on it, it does not get the focus nor lets me input any text on it. I tryed to add a key listener to the `JPanel` (which is the base of the form) so that when I type text, it would keep it in a string variable and dump it to the method as soon as I pressed return.

I need help to sort out what's happening. Did not post any code, because the form is copyrighted to its fullest. Really need some ideas on how to get around this problem.

Here's the part of the code where I try to add the listener.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    MyButton jb = (MyButton) e.getSource();
    String buttonGetName = jb.getName();

    /* MÉTODO PARA CAPTURA DE ENTRADAS POR TECLADO / LEITOR DE COD BARRAS */
    back.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                barcode.setText(sBarcode);
                System.out.println("sBarcode");
                sBarcode = null;
            } else {
                System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
                sBarcode = sBarcode + e.getKeyChar();
            }
        }
    });
```

... some more code here that reads which button is pressed in an array of buttons.

Comment: not possible without posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, complilable and remove whatever, just about JTextField, otherwise this question isn't answerable in none of cases

Comment: *"copyrighted to its fullest."*  LOL - the thought of someone trying to steal code that is already known to be broken.  You made my day.  :)

Comment: I know only one (real) example for that, in the case  `JTextComponent` is placed into `JWindow`, then there not possible any input from KeyBoard, real reason == don't know, maybe is there real reason for this implementation in API

Comment: I'll try to be as clear as possible so that it can be a clue on how im trying to do it:

Comment: A wild guess ... do you use an `InputVerifier` which does not allow to switch the focus to your new text field until you filled out the other text field correctly ?

Comment: *"as clear as possible"*  You cannot get much more clear than an SSCCE.

Comment: Glad i made your day Andrew :). I'm a newbie in java development and i've been given a full app to remake to a different platform, screen size and hardware all together. Basicly im in panic mode right now :P.

Comment: The key listener code was slightly adapted from an stackoverflow answer i searched before.

Comment: question without edited code was more clear, sorry I take that as joke, please whats Glad i made your day Andrew :) ???

Comment: *"... some more code here"*  An SSCCE requires that code, the imports, and a `main(String[])` to throw it on-screen. *"Basicly im in panic mode right now"*  Take a break, get a good night's sleep, come back to it tomorrow and read the SSCCE document.  If the process of making an SSCCE does not solve the problem for you, we will at least have a good chance of spotting the error in the final code.

Comment: Note that the code you posted has nothing to do with a `JTextField` ...

Comment: No jokes here, just plain old "don't know what to do and how to do it".  Most of the form is built at run time and the rest is basically a bunch of event handlers to check what's been clicked. Its close to 1500 lines of code and most of it is just getting items description and format from a database and putting them into containers. Please help me try to be more clear about the question. What else can i post?

Comment: @CJ Mendes [I'd to suggest to use proper Forum for your ask is here](http://www.vworker.com/), because there are only volunteers and with cost free, and with volatille interest about whatever

Comment: *What else can i post?"*  I could write an SSCCE of adding a new text-field to a panel on button click in less than 50 lines of code.  So for the moment, ***forget*** the 1500 lines of code with multiple ..whatevers and create a short example with one button that creates a new text-field.  Further, don't think of this process as 'the long way around'.  It will take much longer for anyone to randomly guess where the problem is in the code we cannot see.

Answer (score 2):

- don't to use [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for [`JTextComponents`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html), use `Document`, `DocumentFilter`, [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) instead (depends on real requirements)
- [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) isn't designated for listening from `Swing JComponents`, use proper [`Listener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html) instead
- for any type of `short_cuts` to use [`KeyBindings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer even if i wasn't the best at presenting code and/or problem. I'll give it a go.